# permission-denied while setting a new Admin in GDI CLI

Tags: reactjs, firebase, gdi-cms

I've followed the GDI [documentation](https://github.com/dht/gdi) to install a new instance:

1. Created a new Firebase Project
2. Enabled Authentication, Firestore and Storage
3. Successfully ran it locally

And yet when I run:

```bash
gdi setAdmin
```

I get a permission error:

```markdown
[2022-12-11T08:19:37.032Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.14.0_lite): RestConnection RunQuery failed with error:  [FirebaseError: Request failed with error: Missing or insufficient permissions.] {
  code: 'permission-denied',
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which `gdi` CLI version are you trying to run?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).